# emberjs plugin for vim

Tags: vim, autocomplete, ember.js

I am trying to use VIM as an editor for my emberjs work. I have some of the well know plugins installed for VIM

1. vim-snipmate
2. vim-snippets
3. doctorjs

for auto completion, and source code browsing. Now when i write code in vim, it does not understand the Ember's methods and classes for auto completion.

I am a tried finding some snippets for emberjs but i did not find any.

Can anyone help in telling how to they do coding for emberjs if using VIM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of those plugins provide autocompletion.

Omni completion (`<C-x><C-o>`) should work by default if the `ember.js` file is in the same directory as the file you are editing.

Comment: If it is not present in the same directory i tried opening the ember.js file in the VIM buffer, and it started working with ctrl+p key combination.

Comment: for starters i opened the file in the buffer using a plugin for vim calle NERDTree, The tutorials is mentioned here http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/vim-essential-plugin-nerdtree/ so once i opened the file auto completion worked

Comment: Raah… Someone should issue a formal DMCA complaint to all those stupid sites who advise new users to install useless plugins.